# Why does logger.get_logger(__name__) always work?

Tags: python, logging

`logger.get_logger(__name__)` sometimes returns `__main__`, and sometimes return the `module.file_name`. When it returns `__main__`, it may conflict with other loggers also named as `'__main__'`.

Why shouldn't I get `__file__` variable and parse the string to get the module name, instead of sometimes `__main__`?

Comment: *What* "other loggers also named as `'__main__'`"?

Comment: Different files may produce '__main__'?

Comment: When do you think that would happen? Why aren't you worried about two loggers named `foo` or `anything_else` conflicting?

Comment: OK. At the same time, there is only one possible __main__. Is that right? No multiples. I thought in a big project with multiple modules, there may be more __main__, which may be wrong.

Comment: @marlon there can only be one `__main__`